# Can't find image/child that was just created

Tags: c#, wpf

C#
My code is in this order:

1. create and add an image as a child
2. switch to the tab where the image has been added
3. run code based on that child/image

My problem is, when number 3 runs, it can't find the child, and things break.  It get's weird, if I put a MessageBox.Show() right after number 2, then click OK on the MessageBox, then number 3 runs correctly, it finds the child. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you paste your relevant code here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting an DoEvents() just before #3.

Because of the MessageBox you are letting the application pump all the messages, so with the DoEvents() you are pumping the messages.

I create a similar method to the Forms Application.DoEvents() to pump messages in WPF with this code,

```
public static void DoEvents()
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(delegate { }));
}
```

It can't be called often, but it can help sometimes.